# Display images/links in html using xslt

Tags: html, xml, maven, xslt

I am generating HTML reports using the tesng-xslt library with input of "testng-results.xml" which is generated by Maven surefire-reports. I am using Reporter.log for reporting. In this I am also attaching screenshots using reporter.log as below

```
Reporter.log("<img src=\"file:///" + screenshotAbsolutePath + "\" alt=\"\"/><br />");
```

So the image is displayed in report generated by maven surefire plug in in reporter-output. Now when I generate HTML report through testng-xslt library with build.xml, images are not displayed in HTML

please find  xml used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="2" total="2" passed="0">
  <reporter-output>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[Successfully Launced the Url - https://stg.xxxxx.com/asp/gateway/discovery]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[Successfully Entered email 'qatest2850@test.com' in UserName Field]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[Successfully Clicked on Next Button]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[Successfully clicked on Forgot Password]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[<img src="file:///D:\CertMetric\cspweb\screenshots\1492095605697.png" alt=""/><br />]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[Failed to send Email]]>
    </line>
</reporter-output>
<suite>
<test>
<class>
<test-method>
</test-method>
</class>
</test>
</suite>
</testng-results>
```

the data is in  and xslt for reporter-output

```
 <xsl:result-document href="{testng:absolutePath('reporterOutput.html')}" format="xhtml">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <xsl:call-template name="htmlHead"/>
                <body>
                    <h2>Reporter output</h2>
                    <xsl:for-each select="reporter-output/line">
                        <div>
                            <code>
                              <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                            </code>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:call-template name="powered-by"/>
                </body>
            </html>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template
```

Could anybody help me in this? I want to display images or hyperlinks in HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi can anybody please help me in this